# R markdown syntax

Tags: r-markdown

I have difficulty to make R markdown render some text

I'd like the following R markdown file to show

**`r fun1("label")`** replaces **Table @ref(tab:label)** in Rmd text

Here is my R markdown file:

```
---
title: "test"
output: 
  bookdown::word_document2
---

**`r fun1("label")`** replaces **Table \@ref(tab:label)** in Rmd text
```

but it doesn't work. Can anyone help? The closest I can get is:

```
---
title: "test"
output: 
  bookdown::word_document2
---

**`\r fun1("label")`** replaces **Table `\@ref(tab:label)`** in Rmd text
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use escape characters (backticks) so it doesn't evaluate, just prints. `\x60`  is a symbolic way of represting the backticks as text to create the output you want:

```
---
title: "test"
output: 
  bookdown::word_document2
---

**`` `r '\x60r fun1("label")\x60'` ``** replaces **Table ``\@ref(tab:label)`` ** in Rmd text
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry that I made a small error in my post, I'd like the 2nd bold text to be **Table \@ref(tab:label)**. Also, can you explain your answer in more details?

Comment: Edited answer per @blueskyddd

Comment: Thank you so much! The font of **Table** is different from that of **\@ref(tab:label)** in your answer; but it's good enough! Could you explain the meaning of  ``, '\x60r, \x60' `?

Comment: sorry to bother again! I tried to put **Table** together with **\@ref(tab:label)** so their fonts would be same, but it doesn't work. Can you help?